# PHP - relative paths in index.php are not working as expected

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to update a legacy laravel 4.2 website and decided to move the website to my localhost.

In the public_html folder, the index.php file loads the bootstrap and app files like so:

```
<?php
/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylorotwell@gmail.com>
 */

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader
| for our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll require it
| into the script here so that we do not have to worry about the
| loading of any our classes "manually". Feels great to relax.
|
*/
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let's turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight these users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can simply call the run method,
| which will execute the request and send the response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have whipped up for them.
|
*/

$app->run();
```

But I get the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  require(/home/gras/TenisPremium/public_html/bootstrap/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/gras/TenisPremium/public_html/artisan on line 16
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/gras/TenisPremium/public_html/bootstrap/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/gras/TenisPremium/public_html/artisan on line 16
```

From what I understand it is looking for the folder bootstrap inside public_html even though I specify that I want the parent directory.
Here is my directory structure:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── commands
│   ├── config
│   ├── controllers
│   ├── database
│   ├── helpers
│   ├── lang
│   ├── models
│   ├── service
│   ├── start
│   ├── storage
│   ├── tests
│   └── views
├── bootstrap
├── public_html
│   ├── assets
│   ├── packages
│   └── upload
└── vendor
    ├── artdarek
    ├── bacon
    ├── bin
    ├── classpreloader
    ├── composer
    ├── d11wtq
    ├── davibennun
    ├── doctrine
    ├── facebook
    ├── filp
    ├── gloudemans
    ├── guzzlehttp
    ├── intervention
    ├── ircmaxell
    ├── jeremeamia
    ├── laravel
    ├── lightshire
    ├── maatwebsite
    ├── milon
    ├── monolog
    ├── nesbot
    ├── nikic
    ├── patchwork
    ├── phpoffice
    ├── phpseclib
    ├── predis
    ├── psr
    ├── pusher
    ├── simplesoftwareio
    ├── sly
    ├── stack
    ├── swiftmailer
    ├── symfony
    ├── tijsverkoyen
    ├── way
    └── zendframework
```

Comment: `/../` seeks for directory up the hierarchy. As drawn, there is no file in bootstrap directory. Can you double check and confirm files are there?

Answer (score 0):

Write down exactly what you did.

4.2 doesn't have public_html.

Run `php artisan serve` command in the project root.

Upgrading from 4.2 to latest is not recommended.
Create new project.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade#upgrade-5.0